# How to debug intermittent slow iOS iPhone app load times in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, optimization

I have an iOS Xcode project that previously would load fast, but from time to time, now will hang for five seconds or more during loading. When the app is run on an iPhone, the launch screen displays instantly, but sometimes, not always, and unpredictably, the app just hangs for around 5 seconds or more until the actual interface is displayed. It occurs both on the simulator and device across different iOS versions 7, 8, 9.

Recently, a UIView's class that contains a drawRect function was changed slightly, it has an outlet connection to one of the ViewControllers, but no significant changes made overall. One ViewController has code in the ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear, ViewDidAppear functions. All these things I'm investigating if they are impacting the load time.

When I terminate the app, the next time I try running it, it loads super fast without issue. I have no idea what to make of this load behaviour.

**Questions**

1 - What methods can I use in Xcode to debug an app that loads slowly at irregular and unpredictable times?

2 - What obvious items should I be on the look out in the project that typically cause slow or prolonged load times?

3 - Does Xcode include tools to monitor the processes operating live while loading occurs?

4 - Is it possible to print output for load processes I can review?

Any experienced advice really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To confirm, this occurs on devices running your app, *not connected* to Xcode or debugger?

Comment: @sschale yes, that's correct, running on device, not plugged in or connected to Xcode.

Comment: By "unpredictable" do you also mean rare? If you run the app in the Simulator tied to Xcode 10 or 20 times, will one of them launch slowly? If you can reproduce the problem that often, then it's much easier to debug. Also, such a long lag often suggests networking, so test w/ network turned off and see if it hangs more reliably (even better is to leave networking on but non-routining, but that's a little more complicated if you don't control your network).

Comment: egardless, agree with @Carlos, you should try to capture on Instruments things that might be going awry.

Comment: So, maybe once every ten loads in the simulator. It might load slow after the device has not been used for some time, but not always.

Comment: If it's one in ten, and you get a nice long pause that you tell you're in the middle of, it's not too hard. Just run it in the Simulator until it pauses longer than it should, and hit the "pause" button in the debugger. Look in your stack traces to see where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have looked instrumentation. It is the best way to determine this kind of issues with your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html

> When I terminate the app, the next time I try running it, it loads super fast without issue. I have no idea what to make of this load behavior.

Do you mean exiting the app? Or actually killing it? Cause if it is the former, then the reason is the app was just launched from a suspended state.

I would suggest take a closer look at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and check if you are doing something that takes more time than needed. Run your app with the time profiler instrument, it will tell you where is your bottleneck.

Comment: I have used the instruments before for general overview, but for this problem, I guess I'm looking for something specific in the instruments at launch.Yes, to clarify, when double tap Home button to close the app is what I meant. Sorry, could you please explain what you mean by looking at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, how do I use that exactly?

Comment: I'm suggesting you to look the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Since this is the first thing that get called upon app launch. Time profiler will tell you if anything there is taking longer than usual.